# Solve$\int_{-\pi/4}^{\pi/4}e^{\frac{x}{2}}\frac{\cos x-\sin x}{\sqrt{\cos x}}\,dx$

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

Solve$$\int_{-\pi/4}^{\pi/4}e^{\frac{x}{2}}\frac{\cos x-\sin x}{\sqrt{\cos x}}\,dx$$

I know there maybe some repeated terms that I can finally eliminate without calculation, but I can't find it.

Comment: You can simplify the integral as $\int\limits_{-\pi/4}^{\pi/4} \sqrt{e^xcosx} - \sqrt{e^x secx \; tanx}.$

Comment: @AloysiusGodinho what is the variable  , still $x$?

Comment: @AloysiusGodinho It seems that $secx$ should be $sinx$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get that
$$
\int_{-\pi/4}^{\pi/4} e^{x/2}\frac{\cos x-\sin x}{\sqrt{\cos x}}\,dx=\bigl[2e^{x/2}\sqrt{\cos x}\bigr]_{-\pi/4}^{\pi/4}=2^{7/4}\sinh(\pi/8).
$$
You do the details.

**Update**: This is how I got the primitive.
The integrand can be written as
$$
e^{x/2}\sqrt{\cos x}-e^{x/2}\frac{1}{\sqrt{\cos x}}\sin x.
$$
Now, *if* we would be able to get a simple primitive, it looks like it must be in the form $e^{x/2}f(x)$ for some function $f(x)$, since then we would get two terms, while differentiating. Then, it was just noting that
$$
D\sqrt{x}=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}\quad\text{and}\quad D\cos x=-\sin x,
$$
and hence
$$
D\sqrt{\cos x}=-\frac{1}{2\sqrt{\cos x}}\sin x,
$$
and, up to the constant $2$, it just fitted perfectly.

Comment: It is highly likely that the OP already has the solution, and the details are what they need help with.

Comment: I doubt, but I will happily fill in some details if OP asks for them. In fact, my hope was that the middle step would make OP think, and think again (if necessary), and then get what is going on...

Comment: Yes. I knew the final answer. Can you give a little more information, for example, how you get the anti derivative.

Comment: Rowan, answer is updated with details.

Comment: @mickep Thanks for adding some details and sharing your idea, it's helpful.

Comment: I never meant to keep something as a secret, it was just meant that you should get an "aha-feeling", and do the details... That is a good way of learning, I think.